# Set color behind transparent status bar

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, toolbar, statusbar

I want to be able to change the color behind a transparent status bar. 
I know how to change the status bar color, but then it becomes a solid color and and opening the navigation drawer no longer draws it behind the a translucent status bar.

The cyan color is the primary dark background color. The toolbar has been colored programatically to green, and making darkGreen the primaryDark color is not an option because there are other colors.

(Sort of like the Google+ App, where the Primary/PrimaryDark color seems to be able to change depending on what fragment is selected)

So how can I change the color behind the translucent status bar programatically on runtime, to green?

[image]

[image]

Comment: have You tried putting `<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>` to your theme?

Comment: yes that is already set. The status bar is translucent as I would like it, but I want to change the color behind the status bar.